# Does Maven have a Java Compiler

Tags: java, maven, compiler-specific

In the articles I've read about Maven, I can't tell for sure whether Maven itself has a Java compiler or whether it relies on the compiler in JDK or both.

Comment: It uses the compiler from a locally installed JDK

Comment: Maven uses a Java compiler.  It is not a Java compiler.  It's a lifecycle and dependency management tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven does not have an embedded compiler. Maven requires that you set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable which points to a JDK installation.